# Update firebase database value every 5 seconds using Pub/sub OR Cloud Tasks?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am new to Firebase and I am totally confused about what should I use. Here is my flow.

I have a collection `score` on firebase and it has values

```
- start_time
- count
- max_count
```

Now when `start_time` matches with the current time, I need to increment the `count` every five seconds till it matches `max_count` to the database. This should be in the backend. Now here I got confused. What can be suitable for this?

There are so many documents about Cloud Tasks and Pub/Sub.

If I Call the firebase function from Pub/Sub to update the count every 5 seconds then I will be paying for un-used compute time for calling a function.

I am not aware more about Cloud Tasks that is it matches my requirement? Can anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 1):

Neither Cloud Tasks nor Pub/Sub would be the right solution for this and I wouldn't recommend using a cron-type service for such a menial task.

Instead consider moving the incremental logic to your client and just storing `start_time` and `max_count` in your database.  Here's an example:

```js
// Let's set a start_time 10 seconds in the future and pretend this was in the database
const start_time = Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000) + 10;

// Pretend this came from the database, we only want to iterate 10 times
const max_count = 10;

let prev_count = 0;

document.write("Waiting 10 seconds before starting<br />");

// Let's iterate once a second until we reach the start_time
let interval = setInterval(() => {
  const now = Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
  
  // If it's not start time, exit
  if (now < start_time) return;
  
  // Determine the count by dividing by 5 seconds
  let count = Math.floor((now - start_time) / 5);
  
  if (count > prev_count) {
    document.write(`Tick: ${count}<br />`);
  }
  
  prev_count = count;

  if (count >= max_count) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 1000);
```

If you need the count stored in the database, have it update the `count` value in your database each time it increments.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I need to do increment at the backend and as soon as the count is updated to a new value, the values updated to all users. Whether the user uses or not uses the app but the count is going to increment from the backend.

Comment: The point of the above answer is to help you understand that the clients, frontend or backend whenever they connect, can easily calculate what the count is using the start_time without resorting to cron jobs.  The alternative is to set up Cloud Scheduler and a Cloud Function that executes once a second, every day, forever and hoping that it doesn't skip a beat.  It's just not a scalable option in a microservice architecture.